# Kivy - Black screen issue

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Why am I getting black screen for the below code in kivy?
MyGrid class is not instantiating.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __int__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="First name="))
        self.firstName = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.firstName)


class Myapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Myapp().run()
```

Comment: Can you post the log you get when running the app?

Answer (score 0):

You've written `__int__` instead of `__init__`

Comment: Oh my Bad. Thanks buddy, Now I got expected output.